# Left join on multiple fields returns non-matching rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Is there the possibility that a `LEFT JOIN` on multiple fields will ever select rows with different values for the field? Consider the following query:

```
SELECT A.a aa, A.b ab, B.a ba, B.b bb
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.a = B.a
AND A.b = B.b
WHERE A.a = :filter
```

Here, I expect `aa` and `ba` both be equal to `:filter` at all times (unless null values are involved).

I'm currently having an issue where I get rows in my result that I do not expect and I have to put the condition in the `WHERE` clause. I'm still working on an sqlFiddle to reproduce the issue. Will link to it, once I have it working (but maybe then I'll understand the problem myself)

Changing `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` also solves the problem. But I don't understand why and really want to know the logic behind it.

---

Funnily enough, if I filter `B.a` to be not null (effictively turning the left join into an inner join) I get the expected and identical results to that of an inner join. But without this check, I have numerical values in the selected `B.a` field. Why would they get filtered with `IS NOT NULL` but be displayed with numerical values? Is the Oracle query optimizer doing something fishy?

---

Adding /*+ no_query_transformation */ gives the correct result again.

Execution plans of the different versions are:

- Original query:

  ```
  SELECT STATEMENT
    NESTED LOOPS                        OUTER
      TABLE ACCESS            A         BY INDEX ROWID
        INDEX                 A_B_FK    RANGE SCAN
      VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE   B
        FILTER
          TABLE ACCESS        B         BY INDEX ROWID
            INDEX             B_C_FK    RANGE SCAN
  ```
- Query with `+no_query_transformation`:

  ```
  SELECT STATEMENT
    VIEW
      NESTED LOOPS                  OUTER
        VIEW               A
          TABLE ACCESS     A        BY INDEX ROWID
            INDEX          A_B_FK   RANGE SCAN
        VIEW
          VIEW             B
            TABLE ACCESS   B        FULL
  ```

Comment: My short answer would be no. I am not able to reproduce (11g/XE). Is it possible for you to deliver code sample that can reproduce?

Comment: @JensKrogsboell: thanks for taking the time. I'm still trying to reproduce with sqlFiddle, but I'm unable to do so. Having the issue on Oracle 10g (10.2.0.4.0)

Comment: A long shot could be to try out hint /*+ no_query_transformation */. If this changes the behavior I would say it is the optimizer doing a bad job guessing what you want to do. Never seen that with simple queries though.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell: YES! adding `no_query_transformation` gives the expected result! Adding `b.a IS NOT NULL` gives the correct result, adding `b.a IS NULL` gives zero rows as result. This is really weird.

Comment: I have seen it often in complex queries involving a lot of inline performance views - like e.g. with clause. A wee bit worrying:-)

Comment: some sample data would be useful.. table a, table b and unexpected results?

Comment: @knittl are your optimizer statistics up to date? We had a similar problem on a testenvironment and it turned out statistics where not updated for weeks.

Comment: I support what Alfons says, you could try to a `VACUUM` operation on these tables, just to make sure the stats are up-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll risk my neck:

This is an Oracle optimizer bug causing the optimizer to mis-interpret the intent of the query in the process of transforming the query into something more efficient (merge views etc.).

We can say it is a bug because the no_query_transformation hint changes the result to what would be expected. I am not familiar with any hint expected to change anything but the execution plan - and certainly not the result.

These types of "wrong result" errors are most often seen in complex queries with inline performance views.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Does not fix it (I have to change the query to use the `WHERE` clause), but explains it :)

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour sounds completely expected: it's what a LEFT JOIN does, and fixing it by changing it to an INNER JOIN sort of proves it.

Basically, a LEFT JOIN says (in this case) return all rows from a that match the WHERE clause, and from b all b's that you can match to a selected a, but if there are no b's that match any selected a then return that a anyway with nulls for the values from b.

Changing that to an INNER JOIN will not return a's which don't have any b's. The same effect can be got by excluding null b columns in the where clause as you also note.

This is simply the way LEFT joins behave.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what you should expect. And as I read the question it is exactly what knittl expects but not what he gets;-)

Comment: That's not my reading of it, I'm afraid. For example 'Funnily enough, if I filter B.a to be not null (effictively turning the left join into an inner join) I get the expected and identical results to that of an inner join.' It really sounds to me that he's getting the childless a's and not expecting them; this is why using an inner join fixes the problem.

Comment: Quoting: "Here, I expect aa and ba both be equal to :filter at all times (unless null values are involved)."

Comment: Sure, but read the rest of it. There is another alternative: the join is not properly specified. However I assumed that that wasn't the case. Maybe he should add a.aa = b.ba to the join? There isn't enough information to say whether he should or not. However, that wouldn't explain why using inner join fixes it.

Comment: Would you also see that as an explantion to why result changes with no_query_transformation? Clearly its an Oracle optimizer bug.

Comment: It's not a hint I've used; however my experience of the Oracle optimiser is not good, so I'd be prepared to believe that. However, that still leaves at least an ambiguity in the question...

Comment: @simonatrcl: I understand the difference between inner and outer joins. I don't get any NULL values in my result, but different values for rows that I have specified to be equal in the join clause. It's difficult to explain in words and an SqlFiddle will not reproduce the error (at least I have not managed to recreate it with a fiddle).

Comment: It does sound, then, that @JensKrogsboell is correct, and its a bug in the query optimiser. He's posted an answer above, and it right now I think he's more likely correct than my answer is. Are there any updates you can apply to the Oracle installation?